# jquery ajax and php validation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, validation, forms

I got this kind of form validation:

php side:

```
  if ( trim($message)=="" )
  {
    echo "lalalaal<br>lalalalala";
  }
```

then in the onsuccess ajax jquery:

```
var error=$('div#error_contact').html()
switch(error){

  case "lalalaal<br>lalalalala":
    $("#form_contact").slideUp()
  }
```

if i put a `<br>` the string equality is not verified so de `$("#form_contact")` wont slide up, why the ajax transport doesnt recognize `<br>`  ?

Comment: please fix your examples by adding \`backticks\` around them.. Some elements are missing.

Comment: Why the switch? Do you need different animations for different messages? Why not just check to see if `#error_contact` exists or is non-empty? Your approach will make it a real pain to change any error messages b/c you have to change it in two places and they have to match exactly.

Comment: if ( trim($message)=="" )
  {
    echo "<div style='background-color:#F4B9C7;padding:7px;border:1px solid #C83F68;margin-bottom:4px'><strong>tank you</strong></div>";
  }
if i put something like this it neither works.

Comment: If you're using firebug, use `console.log()` statements to see the difference between the value of error and the string "lalalaal<br>lalalalala" in the console tab. Maybe your <br/> is being escaped or something...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of echoing what you want to say in the php, why don't you try a meaningful message, for example:

```
if ( trim($message)=="" )
{
    echo "la";
}
```

Then, in your front-end:

```
var error=$('div#error_contact').html('')

switch(error){
    case "la":
    $"#some_element").html('lalalaal<br />lalalalala')
    $("#form_contact").slideUp()
}
```